# ansible assign a fact to a variable

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I am trying to get the set_facts assigned but I keep getting error that item not found. Could you please help me how to get this working

```yaml
- name: set facts identification
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  become: true
  vars:
    dir_path:
      - /opt/test1
      - /opt/test2
      - /opt/test3
  tasks:
    - name: set facts identification
      ansible.builtin.stat:
          path: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ dir_path }}"
      register: soe_checks
      
    - name: Set_facts
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        soe: "{% if item.stat.isdir %} 'true' {% else %} 'false' {% endif %}
```

Comment: You're getting item not found issue because in your set_fact task you must loop through your registered soe-checks variable. Also, add a minimum reproducible example and the exact error you are getting.

Comment: The loop is not needed. You can *map* the attribute. Why do you need the exact error? The problem is clear. Also, why do you (plural) want to close it? It's a typical case of cleaning a code by moving the selections into the *vars*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to iterate the results. Instead, declare the variable *soe* in *vars* and select the attribute. Iterate the list *soe* if you want to

```yaml
  soe: "{{ soe_checks.results|map(attribute='stat.isdir')|list }}"
```

---

Note: The filter *map* will fail if any item is missing. Use *json_query* instead

```yaml
  soe: "{{ soe_checks.results|json_query('[].stat.isdir') }}"
```

---

You can also use *set_fact* to 'instantiate' the variable

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        soe: "{{ soe_checks.results|map(attribute='stat.isdir')|list }}"
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── hosts
└── pb.yml

0 directories, 3 files
```

```ini
shell> cat ansible.cfg 
[defaults]
gathering = explicit
collections_path = $HOME/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/
inventory = $PWD/hosts
roles_path = $PWD/roles
remote_tmp = ~/.ansible/tmp
retry_files_enabled = false
stdout_callback = yaml
```

```bash
shell> cat hosts
test_11
test_13
```

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: all

  vars:

    dir_path:
      - /tmp/opt/test1
      - /tmp/opt/test2
      - /tmp/opt/test3

    soe: "{{ soe_checks.results|map(attribute='stat.isdir')|list }}"
    soe_dict: "{{ dict(dir_path|zip(soe)) }}"

  tasks:

    - stat:
        path: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ dir_path }}"
      register: soe_checks

    - debug:
        var: soe|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: soe_dict

    - set_fact:
        soe: "{{ soe_checks.results|map(attribute='stat.isdir')|list }}"
```

Given the directories on the remote hosts

```bash
shell> ssh admin@test_11 ls -l /tmp/opt
total 2
drwxr-xr-x  2 admin  wheel   2 Mar 10 17:01 test1
drwxr-xr-x  2 admin  wheel   2 Mar 10 17:01 test2
lrwxr-xr-x  1 admin  wheel  11 Mar 10 17:02 test3 -> /etc/passwd
```

```bash
shell> ssh admin@test_13 ls -l /tmp/opt
total 2
drwxr-xr-x  2 admin  wheel   2 Mar 10 17:01 test1
drwxr-xr-x  2 admin  wheel   2 Mar 10 17:01 test2
lrwxr-xr-x  1 admin  wheel  11 Mar 10 17:02 test3 -> /etc/passwd
```

The play gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [stat] **********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => (item=/tmp/opt/test1)
ok: [test_13] => (item=/tmp/opt/test1)
ok: [test_11] => (item=/tmp/opt/test2)
ok: [test_13] => (item=/tmp/opt/test2)
ok: [test_11] => (item=/tmp/opt/test3)
ok: [test_13] => (item=/tmp/opt/test3)

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  soe|to_yaml: |-
    [true, true, false]
ok: [test_13] => 
  soe|to_yaml: |-
    [true, true, false]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  soe_dict:
    /tmp/opt/test1: true
    /tmp/opt/test2: true
    /tmp/opt/test3: false
ok: [test_13] => 
  soe_dict:
    /tmp/opt/test1: true
    /tmp/opt/test2: true
    /tmp/opt/test3: false

TASK [set_fact] ******************************************************************************
ok: [test_11]
ok: [test_13]

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
test_11: ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test_13: ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

Q: ***"If one directory is present I should set the facts as true."***

A: Use the test [*any*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-if-a-list-value-is-true) if you want to test that **at least one directory is present**

```yaml
  soe_fact: "{{ soe is any }}"
```

If you want to test that **exactly one directory is present** use this

```yaml
  soe_fact: "{{ soe|select|length == 1 }}"
```

Comment: thank you @Vladimir botka. I have three or more directories, if one directory is present I should set the facts as true.  How to achieve this?

Comment: Use the test [*any*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-if-a-list-value-is-true). I added an example.

Comment: Also why do I get the output like this for soe| to_yaml and for soe_dict as well
`{
  "soe|to_yaml": "<generator object do_map at 0x7fefee3b0270>\n...\n",
  "_ansible_verbose_always": true,
  "_ansible_no_log": false,
  "changed": false
}`
'

Comment: You see the error because of the older Ansible version. Use the filter *list* to explicitly convert the output of *map* to a list. I updated the answer.

Comment: I did exactly what you said 
`soe: "{{ soe_checks.results|map(attribute='stat.isdir')|list }}"' `

but the output shows as below, how to just set the one value as true because all I require is just one folder is there means just mark it as true.
`
    "ansible_facts": {
        "soe": [
            true,
            true,
            true
        ]
    },
    "changed": false`

Comment: I tried the following, 
` - set_fact:
        soe: "{{ soe_checks.results|selectattr('stat.isdir','match','True|true')|map(attribute='stat.isdir')|list | unique}}"
`
But it shows the output 'true' in square bracket, how to remove the bracket and just how the value 'true' alone?
`
TASK [set_fact] ****************************************************************
task path: /runner/project/ansible/test/check_soe.yml:24
ok: [xxxxxxxxxx.com] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "soe": [
            true
        ]
    },
    "changed": false
}
`